# Progressbar.js combine two effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I am trying to combine 2 effects from progressbar.js but I can't get it working. Could somebody take a look and maybe help me out?

This is my codepen with the code that I have so far:

http://codepen.io/stephan-v/pen/MwQQzJ

```
var startColor = '#FC5B3F';
var endColor = '#9ec64d';

window.onload = function onLoad() {
    var circle = new ProgressBar.Circle('.progress', {
        color: startColor,
        duration: 3000,
        easing: 'bounce',
        strokeWidth: 8,

        // Set default step function for all animate calls
        step: function(state, circle, bar) {
            circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
          bar.setText((bar.value() * 100).toFixed(0));
        }
    });

    // This will get the number from the page
    var value = ($('.progress').attr('value') / 100);

    // This will determine the circumference of the circle
    circle.animate(value, {
        from: {color: startColor},
        to: {color: endColor}
    });
};
```

I am trying to combine the percent text with the custom animation. The demo's can be found on this page:

http://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/

I would have no problem rewarding whoever can help me out with this.

Comment: if you remove the circle parameter from the step event, the value shows up fine. check it here http://jsfiddle.net/8xa87k31/475/

Comment: progressbar.js version you are using doesn't have setText() method

Comment: It shows up fine with the percentage but the progressbar does not have the gradient like the example does.

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/8xa87k31/476/ this one gives you the gradient and the percentage as well

Comment: @Stephan-v did this last fiddle help??

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you so much for helping me out here.

Comment: @Stephan-v I've posted my answer. please upvote it and mark it as a solution if it helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add  the `step` function in the `circle.animate` method

this is how your `circle.animate` should look

```
circle.animate(value, {
    from: {
        color: startColor
    },
    to: {
        color: endColor
    },
    step: function(state, circle, bar) {
        circle.path.setAttribute('stroke', state.color);
        console.log(circle);
        circle.setText((circle.value() * 100).toFixed(0));
    }
});
```

here's a working **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8xa87k31/476/)** for the same.